# MySQL Dump Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: sql, syntax, mysql

I'm having a MySQL dump from Version 4.0.21. I converted it to UTF-8 to fit with the special characters such as (Ü, ü, Ä, ä, Ö, ö, ß). Now I have to import it into the latest MySQL Version 5.5.36. All data have been imported but an error occurred at the end.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 80769: You have an error in your SQL syntax...use near '' at line 1

The empty string and the line numbers are confusing me. Importing with phpMyAdmin results the same as command line does, with the command:

> mysql -u root -p bugtracker < E:\mantisUTF.dump

The import with the original dump from Version 4.0.21 is working perfect but without the above mentioned special characters.

First Lines of the dump file:

```
-- MySQL dump 9.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: Mantis
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   4.0.21-debug

--
-- Table structure for table `mantis_bug_file_table`
--
```

Last Lines (80768 & 80769):

```
INSERT INTO mantis_user_table VALUES (57,'fullName','firstName lastName','emailAdress','dd1875c93e8f17a24ebaf9c902b7165a','2014-01-29 13:43:21','2014-03-26 13:22:47',1,0,55,14,0,0,'1b886436b0c62598ab66e40ae89f0c016dc5777ebb601a73f2a07536281113ae'
```

Thanks in advance.

Relax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rechecking my question i found the problem. The problem was a missing ')' at the end of the dump file.

Last line:

```
INSERT INTO mantis_user_table VALUES (57,'fullName','firstName lastName','emailAdress','dd1875c93e8f17a24ebaf9c902b7165a','2014-01-29 13:43:21','2014-03-26 13:22:47',1,0,55,14,0,0,'1b886436b0c62598ab66e40ae89f0c016dc5777ebb601a73f2a07536281113ae')
```